# Can I add Lifecycle management rule to all Azure Storage accounts in my account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have few hundreds Azure Blob Storage Accounts under my Azure account.
I want to add to all of them the same Lifecycle management rule.
Can this be done from the UI without going one by one?
(I know I can write a script to do it, I was wondering if it is possible also from the UI)

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer to your question is no - **you cannot perform bulk lifecycle update through the portal**.

The closest thing would be an existing [**Azure Automation Runbook**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro) for that, but I did not find any. You can create your own if it make sense. Here you can see an example how it looks:
[image]

Code is a pure powershell:

[image]

But if this is one-time task I would go with Azure CLI or Powershell script.